# Vim - prevent saving/writing a file if it contains certain string

Tags: vim

I'd like to prevent Vim from saving a file if it contains the following text

```
:style=>
```

This could potentially be in multiple places in the file.

As a bonus if it could come up with an error message like "stop putting styles inline!" that would be great too ;)

Thanks!

PS : I would like this prevent action to be triggered upon attempting to write the file :w

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### *One* way

to do this is to "bind" the save (`:w`) command to a function that checks for your pattern:

```
autocmd BufWriteCmd * call CheckWrite()
```

where your `Check()` function could look like this:

```
function! CheckWrite()
  let contents=getline(1,"$")
  if match(contents,":style=>") >= 0
    echohl WarningMsg | echo "stop putting styles inline!" | echohl None
  else
    call writefile(contents, bufname("%"))
    set nomodified
  endif
endfunction
```

Note that in this case you have to provide a "save-file" mechanism yourself (probably a not so good idea, but works well).

---

#### A safer way

would be to `set readonly` when your pattern appears:

```
autocmd InsertLeave * call CheckRO()
```

and issue the warning when you try to save:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * call Warnme()
```

where `CheckRO()` and `Warnme()` would be something like:

```
function! CheckRO()
  if match(getline(1,"$"),":style=>") >= 0
    set ro
  else
    set noro
  endif
endfunction
function! Warnme()
  if match(getline(1,"$"),":style=>") >= 0
    echohl WarningMsg | echo "stop putting styles inline!" | echohl None
  endif
endfunction
```

---

#### Highlight

It is also probably a good idea to highlight your pattern with a `hi`+`syntax match` command:

```
syntax match STOPPER /:style=>/
hi STOPPER ctermbg=red
```

---

Finally, have a look at [this script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1431).

Comment: Use `BufWritePre` instead of `InsertLeave`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more typical to enforce restrictions like this through your VCS's commit hook. See, for example, http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.

This would leave the capabilities of your editor intact while forbidding committing offending code.

Comment: true.  Thats one way of tackling it.  I just wanted something a little more immediate.  Thought there may be something simple I can setup within VIM to help.