# Prevent file saving during BufWritePre

Tags: vim

I have a function which performs validity checking on the current file (so as to conform to my employer's coding standards). I would like to call this function before saving, i.e. using BufWritePre. However, I would to prevent saving the file if it fails my checking function.

So, is it possible to break out of the BufWritePre autocommand?

I realise that I could accomplish this by re-mapping the `:write` command as illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126297/vim-prevent-saving-writing-a-file-if-it-contains-certain-string), but I would like to avoid that if at all possible, as it feels somewhat un-subtle.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: See also the question "[Prevent saving files with certain names in Vim](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6210946/254635)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can 'simply' force an error:

```
:autocmd BufWritePre *.txt throw "you may not"
```

If you wanted to be able to save .txt files again

```
:autocmd!
:source $MYVIMRC
```

Comment: This is much simpler than what I concocted.  I'm guessing that using `:w!` will force through this error?

Comment: No, `w!` does not write anyway

Comment: Thanks! That looks very promising. However, the "error detected" message looks quite ugly... can the error be handled so that it echos a meaningful message, but still leaves the function without saving? I'm not experienced enough in the ways of try/catch/endtry to know if this is possible.

Comment: Me neither, Prince! (+1 for the greate screenname, BTW)

Answer (score 1):

From `:help BufWriteCmd`

```
                            *BufWriteCmd*
BufWriteCmd         Before writing the whole buffer to a file.
                Should do the writing of the file and reset
                'modified' if successful, unless '+' is in
                'cpo' and writing to another file |cpo-+|.
                The buffer contents should not be changed.
                |Cmd-event|
```

So it sounds like you could implement that autocommand, and only do the save and reset `'modified'` if the save is allowed.

I'm guessing that you'd have to use something like `writefile(getline('^', '$'))` to actually do the writing.

On the other hand, you might be able to do something like

- disable your BufWriteCmd autocommand
- `:write` the file again.  I'm not sure if it will let you do this from within the BufWriteCmd handler.
- re-enable your BufWriteCmd autocommand.  You should probably put this in a `:finally` clause to ensure that it executes even if there are problems with the write.