# How to save only the buffers in the visible tab?

Tags: vim, tabs, save

I work like this in VIM :

- First tab displays buffers that I'm modifying
- Other tabs display buffers that I just read/consult

Sometimes I accidentally modify buffers in the other tabs but do not want to save the changes for those buffers.

How can I save only the buffers displayed in the first (current) tab?

Comment: `:set readonly` Found in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126472/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+prevent+writing

Comment: And `:windo update` for writing to disk every modified buffer displayed in a window in the current tab page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said @romainl, to save modifications of (only) the currently displayed buffers, do :

```
:windo update
```